# How to document and test interfaces required of formal parameters in Python 2?

Tags: python, interface, annotations

To ask my very specific question I find I need quite a long introduction to motivate and explain it -- I promise there's a proper question at the end!

While reading part of a large Python codebase, sometimes one comes across code where the interface required of an argument is not obvious from "nearby" code in the same module or package.  As an example:

```
def make_factory(schema):
    entity = schema.get_entity()
    ...
```

There might be many "schemas" and "factories" that the code deals with, and "def get_entity()" might be quite common too (or perhaps the function doesn't call *any* methods on schema, but just passes it to another function).  So a quick grep isn't always helpful to find out more about what "schema" is (and the same goes for the return type).  Though "duck typing" is a nice feature of Python, sometimes the uncertainty in a reader's mind about the interface of arguments passed in as the "schema" gets in the way of quickly understanding the code (and the same goes for uncertainty about typical concrete classes that implement the interface).  Looking at the automated tests can help, but explicit documentation can be better because it's quicker to read.  Any such documentation is best when it can itself be tested so that it doesn't get out of date.

Doctests are one possible approach to solving this problem, but that's not what this question is about.

Python 3 has a "parameter annotations" feature (part of the function annotations feature, defined in PEP 3107).  The uses to which that feature might be put aren't defined by the language, but it can be used for this purpose.  That might look like this:

```
def make_factory(schema: "xml_schema"):
    ...
```

Here, "xml_schema" identifies a Python interface that the argument passed to this function should support.  Elsewhere there would be code that defines that interface in terms of attributes, methods & their argument signatures, etc. and code that allows introspection to verify whether particular objects provide an interface (perhaps implemented using something like zope.interface / zope.schema).  Note that this doesn't necessarily mean that the interface gets checked every time an argument is passed, nor that static analysis is done.  Rather, the motivation of defining the interface is to provide ways to write automated tests that verify that this documentation isn't out of date (they might be fairly generic tests so that you don't have to write a new test for each function that uses the parameters, or you might turn on run-time interface checking but only when you run your unit tests).  You can go further and annotate the interface of the return value, which I won't illustrate.

So, the question:

I want to do exactly that, but using Python 2 instead of Python 3.  Python 2 doesn't have the function annotations feature.  What's the "closest thing" in Python 2?  Clearly there is more than one way to do it, but I suspect there is one (relatively) obvious way to do it.

For extra points: name a library that implements the one obvious way.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [`plac`](http://micheles.googlecode.com/hg/plac/doc/plac.html#plac-for-python-2-x-users) that uses annotations to define a command-line interface for a script. On Python 2.x it uses [`plac.annotations()` decorator](http://code.google.com/p/micheles/source/browse/plac/plac_core.py#42).

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing is, I believe, an annotation library called [PyAnno](http://www.fightingquaker.com/pyanno/).

From the project webpage:

"The Pyanno annotations have two functions:

- Provide a structured way to document Python code
- Perform limited run-time checking "

Comment: That project provides ways to check types, not to document interfaces.  Also, it uses decorators that wrap the decorated function.  I'm not a priori opposed to use of decorators here, but if they're used for this purpose they should probably just mutate the decorated function object and then return it, rather than wrapping the decorated function in a new function -- otherwise, it's very intrusive for something that's just documentation and that may be used all over the codebase.